# Items in my Amazon S3 bucket are publicly accessible. How do I restrict access so that the Bucket link is only accessible from within my app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, server, bucket

I have an Amazon S3 bucket that contains items. These are accessible by anyone at the moment with a link. The link includes a UUID so the chances of someone actually accessing it are very low. Nonetheless, with GDPR around the corner, I'm anxious to get it tied down.

I'm not really sure what to google to find an answer, and having searched around I'm not closer to my answer. I wondered if someone else had a solution to this problem? I'd like to only be able to access the resources if I'm clicking on the link from within my app.

Comment: Do your end users each have iam users setup? If not your probably looking for cloudfront+s3 and use a feature called signed urls.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4), you should be able to restrict access to S3 objects to certain HTTP referrers, with an explicit `deny` to block access to anyone outside of your app:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "http referer policy example",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Allow get requests referred by www.example.com and example.com.",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": "*",
       "Action": "s3:GetObject",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
       "Condition": {
         "StringLike": {"aws:Referer": ["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
       }
     },
      {
        "Sid": "Explicit deny to ensure requests are allowed only from specific referer.",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
        "Condition": {
          "StringNotLike": {"aws:Referer": ["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

The prerequisite for using this setup would be to build an S3 link wrapper service and hosting it at some site for your app.

Comment: Hey Adil, thanks for this. I put this in place but it blocks access to the item completely, even when I've put in the proper referrer URLs in the StringLike and StringNotLike parts

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard use-case for using a [Pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

Basically, when your application generates the HTML page that contains a link, it generates a special URL that includes an expiry time. It then inserts that URL in the HTML link code (eg for an image, you would use: `<img src='[PRE-SIGNED URL]'/>`

The code to generate the pre-signed URL is quite simple (and is provided in most SDKs).

Keep your Amazon S3 bucket as private so that other people cannot access the content. Then, anyone with a valid pre-signed URL will get the content.